# Signed PKG Installer cannot be opened

Tags: macos, dmg, productbuild

I am trying to distribute my application for Mac OS X.
I have signed PKG installer for my application.
I put it into the DMG file and upload to the server to users can download it.

But when my User opens DMG file, double click on PKG, the system says that the installer is from undefined developer.

The PKG is signed correctly.

Why the system thinks that it from undefined developer?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show how you are creating and signing your installer from the `productbuild` tool? It should be only one or two lines.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.   <br/>I found a soulution. <br/>I was confused with singing certificates. I used "3rd party....", but should "Develepoer ID...". <br/>It seems that I am not alone with my confusion: <br/>https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5501962?tstart=0